# How to keep my heroku app working during new version deployment?

Tags: node.js, heroku

I've noticed that my app stop working briefly (all processes are killed) during the deployment of a new build. This cause the failure of many critical requests that are crucial for the life of the whole application.

Any suggestion to keep my apps working no matter what and especially in case of new version deployment ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the free tier dynos for production apps. Free tier only allows one dyno, so you can't have one spinning up while the other is acting as your production server. Hence, they shut down during new deploys. Paid tier stays up until the new dyno is ready then a swap is done.

If you aren't using free tier dynos, this is rather interesting. Unless you did a "restart all dynos", that shouldn't be the case. You could try using multiple dynos then. Typically heroku does a sequential shutdown for multiple dynos, so one remains running.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this explanation. this makes it all clear for me now. I actually use the hobby tier (7$) but yes that's only 1 dyno. Now, I will consider upgrading to 2 dynos in order to ensure 100% availability.